# background-image not visible in ie11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to generate a process-map using background-images applied to list items.

The `background-image` applied to the list item is not visible in IE11(all versions IE10,9,etc).

CSS CODE

```
      body{padding: 50px 0;}
        .status-line {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto 3%;
      }

     .status-line ul li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    background-image: url("../images/middleCircle.png");
    background-size: 190px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
      }
     .status-line ul li:first-child {
      background-image: url("../images/first-circle.png");
     }
     .status-line ul li:last-child {
    background-image: url("../images/endcircle.png");
    background-size: 34px;
      }
     .status-line span {
    padding: 7px 0 2px 0;
    width: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 3px 0 0 8px;
    color: rgb(153,153,153);
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inherit;
      }
    .status-line #step3{
    /*font-size: 14px;*/
    padding: 7px 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24px;
    }
    .status-line ul li:first-child span {
    margin-left: 3px;
    }
    .status-line ul li  .process-done {
    padding: 20px 0 4px 0;
    background: #0abc70 url("../images/tick-mark.png");
    background-size: 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    }
    .status-line ul li  .processing {
    background: #5776e3;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
```

HTML CODE:

```
       <ul class="cf">
                            <li><span id="step1" class="process-done"></span><h1>Application<br>     Received</h1>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span id="step2" class="process-done"></span><h1>Requirements<br> Received &amp; Reviewed</h1>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span id="step3" class="processing">
                                    3
                                </span><h1>Offer</h1>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span id="step4">
                                    4
                                </span><h1>Offer <br> Accepted</h1>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

I am attaching the screenshots of how it is visible in IE,chrome,firefox.

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVx7V.png)

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLsPt.png)

[IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7ByI.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's name you image?

Comment: I tried to create a jsfiddle based on your code and got a complete mess, some elements and/or styles are missing.  Please create something that works; it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: I did a very hashed-together fiddle and it worked for me in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/j4ktsdbz/1/ All I changed was the css for `ul` and `h1` to try and match your images.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your IE Setting are set to show pictures.

To adjust Internet Explorer so it can display images, do the following:

- Open Internet Explorer.
- Click the Tools menu, and then click Internet Options.
- Click the Advanced tab.
- Scroll down the Settings list until you see Multimedia.
- Make sure that the Show Pictures check box is selected.
- Click OK, and then click OK again.